# Terminal Question: Been trying to escape this screen with "^X + Enter" but it doesnt work

Tags: command-line

I'm transitioning from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and in Ubuntu I want to work with React Native expo framework which is a framework for hybrid mobile development.

I have been struggling to find a proper tutorial to install the expo cli for react native in Ubuntu and have been following a Russian tutorial but I do not know any Russian so just using common sense to guide me soo far.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4j_m_T0u8xU this is the tutorial I'm following but at 3:10 mark of the video, I have no idea how he got that screen which those checkboxes and i do not understand what they mean either. While testing out different methods to bring the screen up I  mistakenly opened up this and entering the command "^X" followed by the enter key did not work. It just send me to the next line. So how should I escape this screen ?

**Picture of where I'm stuck:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiHLZ.png

Comment: At the top of the terminal window, it says which application you're in: "Nano"
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nano/Basics_Guide#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20save,Y%20in%20case%20you%20do.
quick answer: `ctrl + x`

Comment: Ctrl + x worked , thank you Smurfz87 and  thank you Martin for the useful link as well 

Comment: Just FYI: if you're not familiar with terminal based text editors, when you see tutorials online showing commands like `nano filename` or `vim filename`, with or without `sudo` beforehand, you can replace `nano` or `vim` with `gedit`, which is a graphical text editor that will probably be more familiar to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nomenclature "^X" means press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

Comment: Thank you soo much 

Comment: @runnerslog You're welcome, and welcome to AskUbuntu

Comment: Thank You Charles , this is a great welcome 